# How do I make it show up how many questions the user gets right?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple Algebra quiz in HTML and JavaScript, but can't figure out how to make it show up how many answers you got correct. I made it to where the it would turn the correct answer variables into booleans, true is correct and false is incorrect. Then I made if and else statements to see how many answers were correct but the alert (which will be changed) is just displaying zero no matter what. Here is a link to my code.
https://jsbin.com/yivapi/edit?,js

Comment: Voting to close- Too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: `var correct = 0`. Increment that variable every time a question is answered correctly and show it when the quiz is over. What's the difficulty?

Comment: @Andy This. Side note, try doing this with a loop instead of a massive if/else tree

Comment: The variable is not incrementing, I am new to JavaScript and don't know what to do. @Andy

Comment: Huh. Now I've looked at your code is see you already have a variable called `correctAnswers`. I'm more confused now.

Comment: Could you please show an example of what should be done? @Andy

Comment: In your function where you've got something like `var correctAnswers1 = correctAnswers + 1;` just do `correctAnswers++`, and then `alert(correctAnswers)` at the end.

Comment: Ok I will this thank you. @Andy

Comment: In essence, you should have *one* variable that records the number of correct answers, not 15 separate ones.

Comment: It still isn't showing up how many are correct... Am I doing something else wrong? @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trenner, I'm not going to be able to answer your question properly without untangling your code, so what I thought I'd do is show you a different (and hopefully easier) way to approach the problem. I hope that's okay.

**HTML**

Here are the inputs for the questions as I imagine you've set them out. I've only used three here for simplicity. There's a submit button which I'll get to in a moment.

```
<input id="q1" />
<input id="q2" />
<input id="q3" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript**

First we grab our submit button and assign a function `getAnswers` to its click event.

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.onclick = getAnswers;
```

This is a shortcut function to grab the input values so you don't need to keep writing `document.getElementById(id).value` later.

```
function getValue(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

OK. So now, instead of having a load of `if...else` statements we're going to use an object to store all of our information. If you've used other languages they might call something like this a hash map. Basically it's a store of information that has key/value pairs and it's great for storing connected information together. In this case each question is a key which has another object as its value, and that object's keys are `value` and `answer`, and it's values are the value of the input element and the actual answer.

```
function getAnswers() {

    // create the object
    var quiz = {};

    // for each question assign set up a new key (question1)
    // and get the input value using our shortcut function.
    // We set the actual answer here too.
    quiz.question1 = { value: getValue('q1'), answer: '2√19' }
    quiz.question2 = { value: getValue('q2'), answer: '√87' }
    quiz.question3 = { value: getValue('q3'), answer: '8x√2' }

    // Once we've loaded the questions, we can check the answers
    // We pass in our quiz object as an argument
    checkAnswers(quiz);
}
```

Here we use a loop to iterate over our quiz object. A simple loop of 7 lines instead of all those horrible `if...else` statements.

```
function checkAnswers(quiz) {

    // set up out correctAnswers variable
    var correctAnswers = 0;

    // loop over the quiz object and...
    for (var q in quiz) {

        // ...for each question we test the input value we've stored
        // against the answer also held in that object
        // If they match increase the correctAnswers variable
        if (quiz[q].value === quiz[q].answer) {
            correctAnswers++;
        }
    }

    // finally alert the correctAnswers
    alert("You got " + correctAnswers + " out of 15 questions right!");
}
```

[This DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcn4cu3m/5/) will show you the working code. Just add `2√19` into the first input box and press submit and you will get an alert of 1 correct answer(s).

Sorry for not directly answering your question, but I hope you find this code interesting and useful. Good luck with your JavaScript coding.